# add and remove index of form array similar to query builder

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with three input box and a map method so when I enter to add it create the same form below the button when I remove the specific index then it removes the last index, not that specific one although it shows correct data in the console.

```
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    wk: [
      {
        companyName: "",
        reasonForChange: "",
        role: ""
      }
    ]
  });
  const [wkArray, setWkArray] = useState([1]);
```

you can test the whole code with this URL - https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-star-08hyke?file=/src/App.js

Comment: yes, i want to remove the row for the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to bind the `input` values with the `state` so they can be updated when re-rendering according to the state change. So the `input` should look like:

```
         <input
                placeholder="company name"
                value={item.companyName}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  let temp = [...formData?.wk];
                  temp[index].companyName = e?.target?.value;
                  setFormData({ ...formData, wk: temp });
                }}
              />
```

Here's the working code.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    wk: [
      {
        companyName: "",
        reasonForChange: "",
        role: ""
      }
    ]
  });
  const [wkArray, setWkArray] = useState([1]);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(wkArray, formData)}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setWkArray([...wkArray, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)]);
          setFormData({
            ...formData,
            wk: [
              ...formData?.wk,
              {
                companyName: "",
                role: "",
                reasonForChange: ""
              }
            ]
          });
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      {formData.wk?.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            {formData.wk?.length >= 1 && (
              <button
                onClick={(e) => {
                  setWkArray(
                    wkArray.filter((_, i) => {
                      return i !== index;
                    })
                  );
                  setFormData({
                    wk: formData.wk.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
                  });
                }}
              >
                X
              </button>
            )}
            <div>
              <input
                placeholder="company name"
                value={item.companyName}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  let temp = [...formData?.wk];
                  temp[index].companyName = e?.target?.value;
                  setFormData({ ...formData, wk: temp });
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                placeholder="reason for change"
                value={item.reasonForChange}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  let temp = [...formData?.wk];
                  temp[index].reasonForChange = e?.target?.value;
                  setFormData({ ...formData, wk: temp });
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                placeholder="role"
                value={item.role}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  let temp = [...formData?.wk];
                  temp[index].role = e?.target?.value;
                  setFormData({ ...formData, wk: temp });
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

You can see the live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-fermat-jtpcli?file=/src/App.js

I have made some minor changes to improve the code.